# How to add a number to the date ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have method:

```
def date_of_next()
 date = Date.parse('Monday')
 delta = date > Date.today ? 0 : 7
 date + delta
 return date.strftime('%Y-%w-%d'), (date + 7).strftime('%Y-%w-%d')
end
```

This method specifies the date of Monday this week.
In return, I also return the date of Monday next week, but it does not display the date that needs to be

if I run this method in the .rb file then it prints everything well

```
 2019-01-28
 2019-02-4
```

but if run this method in rails controller, there is a problem with the date

```
2019-01-28
2019-01-04
```

As you see, there is a problem with the date of the month.
I do not understand what the problem is, help

Comment: Can you post how your DateTime/UTC is setting on yout rails application?

Comment: It's conventional in Ruby to omit empty arguments, so `def date_of_next` is all you need, no `()` on the end. Likewise, Ruby implicitly returns the last value, so the `return` on the last line is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going a little heavy on your code for a method that returns Monday this Week and Monday next week.

```
 def beginning_of_weeks
   monday = Date.new.beginning_of_week
   return monday, monday + 7.days
 end
```

You can, of course, add the formatting function `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` inside the method, though it would be better organized somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mixed date format?

```
def date_of_next()
 date = Date.parse('Monday')
 delta = date > Date.today ? 0 : 7
 date + delta
 return date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), (date + 7).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end
```

Comment: I checked whether there was a problem, but it did not change anything

Comment: You really want to use the `'%Y-%w-%d'`, `%w` returns the number of week day

Comment: if you use format '%Y-%w-%d' you couldn't get 28-01-2019
04-02-2019

Comment: Also `date.next_week.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`. `%w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)`, so Monday is 1.